# Correlation vs. logit coefficient

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, dataset, sparse

I am analysing a data set with a dichotomous independent and a dichotomous depenent variable. Persons r only is r = 0.047. However, if I use the same variables in a logistic regression the logit-coefficient is 1.123, which gives an exp(b) of 3.074. So, based on the bivariate correlation one might conclude the relationship is very small, based on the bivariate logistic regression one might conclude the relationship between the variables is substantial. Is this a  known phenomenon? One characteristic of the data is that in both the dependent and the independent variable the categories are very uneven - 98% zeros, 2% ones. Can anybody help me  out here in understanding what might be going on?

Thank you very much
Nina